# IllegalStateException In Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, illegalstateexception

This is from book **Professional Java For Web**

> The first time you call getParameter, getParameterMap,
>   getParameterNames, or getParameterValues on a request object, the web
>   container determines whether the request contains post variables, and
>   if it does it reads and parses those post variables by obtaining the
>   request’s InputStream. The InputStream of a request can be read only
>   once. If you call getInputStream or getReader on a request containing
>   post variables and then later attempt to retrieve parameters in that
>   request, the attempt to retrieve the parameters results in an
>   IllegalStateException.

And this is my test code:

```
@Override                                                             
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {                        
    String name = req.getParameter("name");                           
    System.out.println(name);                                         
    ServletInputStream inputStream = req.getInputStream();            
    int read = inputStream.read();                                    
    System.out.println(read);                                         
}
```

And when I hit the Servlet with ?name=test I get:

```
test
-1
```

Is there something I am missing? How can I reproduce this Exception?

Comment: Also it says that "if we retrieve parameters on a request containing post variables and then later call getInputStream or getReader, the call to getInputStream or getReader fails with an IllegalStateException."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have written a `doGet`. In the HTTP GET method, the data is passed through the URL (in the form of `?name1=value1&name2=value2...`), not through the input stream.

To process POST variables, you have to write a `doPost` method and provide the data using a form (at least that's the usual way).

Note also that the book says that to get the exception, you have to open the stream first, then attempt to access the parameter. Not the other way around as you have written.

Comment: protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, 
 IOException {
  
  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(1000);
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(request.getInputStream());
     while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
   stringBuilder.append(scanner.nextLine());
     }
     
  String uid = request.getParameter("uid");
  String pwd = request.getParameter("pwd");
  
  System.out.println(uid + ":" + pwd);
  
   

 }

Comment: RealSkeptic... I tried using the doPost method but still i am unable to get the IllegalStateExecption. Though it returned a null value but no Exception.